# Language features added to C++1y so far

Tags: c++, standards, c++14

Can I find somewhere a list of language features that have been accepted into the C++1y working paper so far, preferrably with links to the proposal papers that have been merged?

http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html suggests that N3386 ("Return type deduction for normal functions") may have been accepted, but I'm wondering where one goes to check this officially (besides manually examining the latest working draft to see whether a paper's proposed wording has been merged).

Comment: There's some good stuff on C++14 and C++17 (hopefully) here: http://isocpp.org/

Comment: It is not a draft, it is an approved standard.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: I am speaking about C++1y, the next version of the standard after C++11. That is not approved yet.

Comment: @HighCommander4: That should be C++2y then :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko It's planned to be C++14, and then C++17 after that.

Comment: @bames53, And the last one was planned to be before 2010 ;) Yes, I know they're getting things together more now than before, which is great for anyone who looks forward to language updates.

Comment: This question doesn't seem all that localized to me, and it would probably help a lot of people to know more about following the standardization process.

Comment: @bames53 I don't get the too localized closure either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple way to figure out if a proposal has been accepted (yet...). The official information is available in the meeting minutes of the meeting where the proposal is voted on. N3386 was in the [pre-Portland 2012 mailing](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/#mailing2012-09), so if you go to the minutes for the [Portland meeting](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3454.pdf) (or, rather, every meeting after the paper is made available which is just the Portland meeting in this case) and go to the section that has the votes you should see if it was approved for application to the working paper. Unless I'm mistaken it wasn't.

Interestingly those meeting minutes includes someone raising the issue of the lack of a list of paper statuses... Another person volunteered to keep such a list, but I don't know if that's been done yet.

---

The [lists of papers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/) seem to have a new column listing the each paper's 'disposition', saying whether a paper has been revised by a newer version or if it's been adopted. I'm uncertain how up-to-date this list is kept, but it seems to be the easiest way to get this information now.